# "Example: Spherical and cartesian grids" isn't compiled to the right figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd just tried to compile [this example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/spherical-and-cartesian-grids/) on my Windows 10 machine, by MiKTeX 2.9, using TeX Maker 4.4.1

The result is supposed to be something like this:

[image]

Whereas, the compilation's output is different:

[image]

**What's the underlying reason for such faulty result?...**

Update 1:

Even with replacing `.estyle` with `.style`, as stated [here](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=25293), the output will not still be the desired figure:

[image]

Update 2:

@marsupilam's primary answer does still not work, completely. The dashed line, as the references of ansgles $\phi_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}$ is not drawn (at least!):

[image]

Comment: I get the same result as you do, and I use TeXlive on Linux.

Comment: In the code of the example, replace `.estyle` by `.style` (two times); however, this will solve the problem only partially. See http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=25293 for more information.

Comment: @gernot: It won't, if you notice to the update. (I thought you've found this is not the solution, as you had said the same thing in your answer; the one you deleted it.)

Comment: As I say in my comment, the fix proposed in the original thread is only a partial fix. But it seems @marsupilam has found a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.estyle` key handler seems broken in TikZ 3.0.1a (it is broken if you use `.add style`, `.prefix style`, `.append style` or any equivalent keys for code) . As a workaround, replace all `.estyle` by `.style/.expanded` (two occurrences in your example).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%% helper macros

% The 3D code is based on The drawing is based on Tomas M. Trzeciak's 
% `Stereographic and cylindrical map projections example`: 
% http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/map-projections/
\newcommand\pgfmathsinandcos[3]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#1{sin(#3)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#2{cos(#3)}%
}
\newcommand\LongitudePlane[3][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % azimuth
  \tikzset{#1/.style/.expanded={cm={\cost,\sint*\sinEl,0,\cosEl,(0,0)}}}
}
\newcommand\LatitudePlane[3][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % latitude
  \pgfmathsetmacro\yshift{\cosEl*\sint}
  \tikzset{#1/.style/.expanded={cm={\cost,0,0,\cost*\sinEl,(0,\yshift)}}} %
}
\newcommand\DrawLongitudeCircle[2][1]{
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
   % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %
  \draw[current plane,thin,black] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:\angVis+180:1);
  \draw[current plane,thin,dashed] (\angVis-180:1) arc (\angVis-180:\angVis:1);
}%this is fake: for drawing the grid
\newcommand\DrawLongitudeCirclered[2][1]{
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
   % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %
  \draw[current plane,red,thick] (150:1) arc (150:180:1);
  %\draw[current plane,dashed] (-50:1) arc (-50:-35:1);
}%for drawing the grid
\newcommand\DLongredd[2][1]{
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
   % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %
  \draw[current plane,black,dashed, ultra thick] (150:1) arc (150:180:1);
}
\newcommand\DLatred[2][1]{
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}
  % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}
  \draw[current plane,dashed,black,ultra thick] (-50:1) arc (-50:-35:1);

}
\newcommand\fillred[2][1]{
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
   % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %
  \draw[current plane,red,thin] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:\angVis+180:1);

}

\newcommand\DrawLatitudeCircle[2][1]{
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}
  % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}
  \draw[current plane,thin,black] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:-\angVis-180:1);
  \draw[current plane,thin,dashed] (180-\angVis:1) arc (180-\angVis:\angVis:1);
}%Defining functions to draw limited latitude circles (for the red mesh)
\newcommand\DrawLatitudeCirclered[2][1]{
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}
  % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}
  %\draw[current plane,red,thick] (-\angVis-50:1) arc (-\angVis-50:-\angVis-20:1);
\draw[current plane,red,thick] (-50:1) arc (-50:-35:1);

}

\tikzset{%
  >=latex,
  inner sep=0pt,%
  outer sep=2pt,%
  mark coordinate/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,
    fill=black,circle}%
}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,every node/.style={minimum size=1cm}]
    %% some definitions

    \def\R{4} % sphere radius

    \def\angEl{25} % elevation angle
    \def\angAz{-100} % azimuth angle
    \def\angPhiOne{-50} % longitude of point P
    \def\angPhiTwo{-35} % longitude of point Q
    \def\angBeta{30} % latitude of point P and Q

    %% working planes

    \pgfmathsetmacro\H{\R*cos(\angEl)} % distance to north pole
    \LongitudePlane[xzplane]{\angEl}{\angAz}
    \LongitudePlane[pzplane]{\angEl}{\angPhiOne}
    \LongitudePlane[qzplane]{\angEl}{\angPhiTwo}
    \LatitudePlane[equator]{\angEl}{0}
    \fill[ball color=white!10] (0,0) circle (\R); % 3D lighting effect
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate[mark coordinate] (N) at (0,\H);
    \coordinate[mark coordinate] (S) at (0,-\H);
    \path[xzplane] (\R,0) coordinate (XE);

    %defining points outsided the area bounded by the sphere
    \path[qzplane] (\angBeta:\R+5.2376) coordinate (XEd);
    \path[pzplane] (\angBeta:\R) coordinate (P);%fino alla sfera
    \path[pzplane] (\angBeta:\R+5.2376) coordinate (Pd);%sfora di una quantità pari a 10 dopo la sfera
    \path[pzplane] (\angBeta:\R+5.2376) coordinate (Td);%sfora di una quantità pari a 10 dopo la sfera
    \path[pzplane] (\R,0) coordinate (PE);
    \path[pzplane] (\R+4,0) coordinate (PEd);
    \path[qzplane] (\angBeta:\R) coordinate (Q);
    \path[qzplane] (\angBeta:\R) coordinate (Qd);%sfora di una quantità pari a 10 dopo la sfera

    \path[qzplane] (\R,0) coordinate (QE);
    \path[qzplane] (\R+4,0) coordinate (QEd);%sfora di una quantità 10 dalla sfera sul piano equat.


    \DrawLongitudeCircle[\R]{\angPhiOne} % pzplane
    \DrawLongitudeCircle[\R]{\angPhiTwo} % qzplane
    \DrawLatitudeCircle[\R]{\angBeta}
    \DrawLatitudeCircle[\R]{0} % equator
    %labelling north and south
    \node[above=8pt] at (N) {$\mathbf{N}$};
    \node[below=8pt] at (S) {$\mathbf{S}$};

    \draw[-,dashed, thick] (N) -- (S);
    \draw[->] (O) -- (P);
    \draw[dashed] (XE) -- (O) -- (PE);
    \draw[dashed] (O) -- (QE);
    %connecting Points outside the sphere
    \draw[-,dashed,black,very thick] (O) -- (Pd);
    \draw[-,dashed,black,very thick] (O) -- (PEd);
    \draw[-,dashed,black,very thick] (O) -- (QEd);
    \draw[-,dashed,black,very thick] (O) -- (XEd);
    \draw[dashed] (XE) -- (O) -- (PE);
    %draw black thick flat grid
    \draw[-,ultra thick,black] (Pd) -- (PEd) node[below, left] {$P_1$};%verticale sinistro
    \draw[-,ultra thick,black] (PEd) -- (QEd)node[below, right] {$P_3$};%orizzontale inferiore
    \draw[-,ultra thick,black] (Pd)-- (XEd)node[above, right] {$P_2$};%orizzontale superiore    
    \draw[-,ultra thick,black] (XEd) -- (QEd);  

    \draw[pzplane,->,thin] (0:0.5*\R) to[bend right=15]
        node[midway,right] {$\lambda$} (\angBeta:0.5*\R);
    \path[pzplane] (0.5*\angBeta:\R) node[right] {$$};
    \path[qzplane] (0.5*\angBeta:\R) node[right] {$$};
    \draw[equator,->,thin] (\angAz:0.5*\R) to[bend right=30]
        node[pos=0.4,above] {$\phi_1$} (\angPhiOne:0.5*\R);
    \draw[equator,->,thin] (\angAz:0.6*\R) to[bend right=35]
        node[midway,below] {$\phi_2$} (\angPhiTwo:0.6*\R);
            \path[xzplane] (0:\R) node[below] {$$};
    \path[xzplane] (\angBeta:\R) node[below left] {$$};
    \foreach \t in {0,2,...,30} { \DrawLatitudeCirclered[\R]{\t} }
    \foreach \t in {130,133,...,145} { \DrawLongitudeCirclered[\R]{\t} }

    %drawing grids on the spere invoking DLongredd and DrawLongitudeCirclered

    \foreach \t in {130,145,...,145} { \DLongredd[\R+3]{\t} }
    \foreach \t in {130,133,...,145} { \DrawLongitudeCirclered[\R+3]{\t} }

    \foreach \t in {0,30,...,30} { \DLatred[\R+3]{\t} }
    \foreach \t in {0,2,...,30} { \DrawLatitudeCirclered[\R+3]{\t} }

    %labelling
    \draw[-latex,thick](4,-5.5)node[left]{$\mathsf{Grid(s)\ in\ Fig. \ (\ref{fig:Grid})}$}
                 to[out=0,in=270] (5.8,-2.3);
    \draw[thick](3.6,-6)node[left]{$[\mathsf{Rectilinear}]$};

\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption[Representation of spherical and regular computational grids used by SWAN]
    {Representation of spherical (red) and cartesian (black) co-ordinate systems. Latter 
    gives an example of unstructured grids. Both unstructured. Conversion from former 
    to latter involves a deformation factor which is acceptable within a given spatial limit. 
    For my case, only unstructured flat meshes are employed (\textit{Lisboa} Geodetic 
    datum: black grid on the right). Confront above represented points ($P_1,P_2,P_3$) with 
    Fig.(\ref{fig:Grid}). \\Mathematically frames change accordingly: see Eq.(\ref{eq:actbal2sph}).}
    \label{fig:frames}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

## Other workaround

You may patch the `.estyle` key handler:

```
\pgfkeys{/handlers/.estyle/.code=%
  \pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.code/.expanded=\noexpand\pgfkeysalso{#1}}}
```

## Note

The bug is in `\pgfkeysedef` and is referenced as [ticket 306](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/306/).

Comment: A much more informed solution than mine ! Thank you Paul.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to **superficially** fix the issue here, but please confer to Paul Gaborit's answer.

**Explanations :**

1. I noticed changing `style` to `estyle` fixed some things while breaking others.
2. I therefore simply define two versions of the `\LongitudePlane` command, one with `estyle` and one with `style` and use empirically the right one when needed.

**The code :**

```
% Author: Marco Miani

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%% helper macros

% The 3D code is based on The drawing is based on Tomas M. Trzeciak's 
% `Stereographic and cylindrical map projections example`: 
% http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/map-projections/
\newcommand\pgfmathsinandcos[3]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#1{sin(#3)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#2{cos(#3)}%
}
\newcommand\LongitudePlaneE[3][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % azimuth
  \tikzset{#1/.estyle={cm={\cost,\sint*\sinEl,0,\cosEl,(0,0)}}}
}
\newcommand\LatitudePlaneE[3][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % latitude
  \pgfmathsetmacro\yshift{\cosEl*\sint}
  \tikzset{#1/.estyle={cm={\cost,0,0,\cost*\sinEl,(0,\yshift)}}} %
}
\newcommand\LongitudePlane[3][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % azimuth
  \tikzset{#1/.style={cm={\cost,\sint*\sinEl,0,\cosEl,(0,0)}}}
}
\newcommand\LatitudePlane[3][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % latitude
  \pgfmathsetmacro\yshift{\cosEl*\sint}
  \tikzset{#1/.style={cm={\cost,0,0,\cost*\sinEl,(0,\yshift)}}} %
}
\newcommand\DrawLongitudeCircle[2][1]{
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
   % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %
  \draw[current plane,thin,black] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:\angVis+180:1);
  \draw[current plane,thin,dashed] (\angVis-180:1) arc (\angVis-180:\angVis:1);
}%this is fake: for drawing the grid
\newcommand\DrawLongitudeCirclered[2][1]{
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
   % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %
  \draw[current plane,red,thick] (150:1) arc (150:180:1);
  %\draw[current plane,dashed] (-50:1) arc (-50:-35:1);
}%for drawing the grid
\newcommand\DLongredd[2][1]{
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
   % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %
  \draw[current plane,black,dashed, ultra thick] (150:1) arc (150:180:1);
}
\newcommand\DLatred[2][1]{
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}
  % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}
  \draw[current plane,dashed,black,ultra thick] (-50:1) arc (-50:-35:1);

}
\newcommand\fillred[2][1]{
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
   % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %
  \draw[current plane,red,thin] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:\angVis+180:1);

}

\newcommand\DrawLatitudeCircle[2][1]{
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}
  % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}
  \draw[current plane,thin,black] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:-\angVis-180:1);
  \draw[current plane,thin,dashed] (180-\angVis:1) arc (180-\angVis:\angVis:1);
}%Defining functions to draw limited latitude circles (for the red mesh)
\newcommand\DrawLatitudeCirclered[2][1]{
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}
  % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}
  %\draw[current plane,red,thick] (-\angVis-50:1) arc (-\angVis-50:-\angVis-20:1);
\draw[current plane,red,thick] (-50:1) arc (-50:-35:1);

}

\tikzset{%
  >=latex,
  inner sep=0pt,%
  outer sep=2pt,%
  mark coordinate/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,
    fill=black,circle}%
}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,every node/.style={minimum size=1cm}]
    %% some definitions

    \def\R{4} % sphere radius

    \def\angEl{25} % elevation angle
    \def\angAz{-100} % azimuth angle
    \def\angPhiOne{-50} % longitude of point P
    \def\angPhiTwo{-35} % longitude of point Q
    \def\angBeta{30} % latitude of point P and Q

    %% working planes

    \pgfmathsetmacro\H{\R*cos(\angEl)} % distance to north pole
    \LongitudePlaneE[xzplane]{\angEl}{\angAz}
    \LongitudePlaneE[pzplane]{\angEl}{\angPhiOne}
    \LongitudePlaneE[qzplane]{\angEl}{\angPhiTwo}
    \LatitudePlane[equator]{\angEl}{0}
    \fill[ball color=white!10] (0,0) circle (\R); % 3D lighting effect
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate[mark coordinate] (N) at (0,\H);
    \coordinate[mark coordinate] (S) at (0,-\H);
    \path[xzplane] (\R,0) coordinate (XE);

    %defining points outsided the area bounded by the sphere
    \path[qzplane] (\angBeta:\R+5.2376) coordinate (XEd);
    \path[pzplane] (\angBeta:\R) coordinate (P);%fino alla sfera
    \path[pzplane] (\angBeta:\R+5.2376) coordinate (Pd);%sfora di una quantità pari a 10 dopo la sfera
    \path[pzplane] (\angBeta:\R+5.2376) coordinate (Td);%sfora di una quantità pari a 10 dopo la sfera
    \path[pzplane] (\R,0) coordinate (PE);
    \path[pzplane] (\R+4,0) coordinate (PEd);
    \path[qzplane] (\angBeta:\R) coordinate (Q);
    \path[qzplane] (\angBeta:\R) coordinate (Qd);%sfora di una quantità pari a 10 dopo la sfera

    \path[qzplane] (\R,0) coordinate (QE);
    \path[qzplane] (\R+4,0) coordinate (QEd);%sfora di una quantità 10 dalla sfera sul piano equat.


    \DrawLongitudeCircle[\R]{\angPhiOne} % pzplane
    \DrawLongitudeCircle[\R]{\angPhiTwo} % qzplane
    \DrawLatitudeCircle[\R]{\angBeta}
    \DrawLatitudeCircle[\R]{0} % equator
    %labelling north and south
    \node[above=8pt] at (N) {$\mathbf{N}$};
    \node[below=8pt] at (S) {$\mathbf{S}$};

    \draw[-,dashed, thick] (N) -- (S);
    \draw[->] (O) -- (P);
    \draw[dashed] (XE) -- (O) -- (PE);
    \draw[dashed] (O) -- (QE);
    %connecting Points outside the sphere
    \draw[-,dashed,black,very thick] (O) -- (Pd);
    \draw[-,dashed,black,very thick] (O) -- (PEd);
    \draw[-,dashed,black,very thick] (O) -- (QEd);
    \draw[-,dashed,black,very thick] (O) -- (XEd);
    \draw[dashed] (XE) -- (O) -- (PE);
    %draw black thick flat grid
    \draw[-,ultra thick,black] (Pd) -- (PEd) node[below, left] {$P_1$};%verticale sinistro
    \draw[-,ultra thick,black] (PEd) -- (QEd)node[below, right] {$P_3$};%orizzontale inferiore
    \draw[-,ultra thick,black] (Pd)-- (XEd)node[above, right] {$P_2$};%orizzontale superiore    
    \draw[-,ultra thick,black] (XEd) -- (QEd);  

    \draw[pzplane,->,thin] (0:0.5*\R) to[bend right=15]
        node[midway,right] {$\lambda$} (\angBeta:0.5*\R);
    \path[pzplane] (0.5*\angBeta:\R) node[right] {$$};
    \path[qzplane] (0.5*\angBeta:\R) node[right] {$$};
    \draw[equator,->,thin] (\angAz:0.5*\R) to[bend right=30]
        node[pos=0.4,above] {$\phi_1$} (\angPhiOne:0.5*\R);
    \draw[equator,->,thin] (\angAz:0.6*\R) to[bend right=35]
        node[midway,below] {$\phi_2$} (\angPhiTwo:0.6*\R);
            \path[xzplane] (0:\R) node[below] {$$};
    \path[xzplane] (\angBeta:\R) node[below left] {$$};
    \foreach \t in {0,2,...,30} { \DrawLatitudeCirclered[\R]{\t} }
    \foreach \t in {130,133,...,145} { \DrawLongitudeCirclered[\R]{\t} }

    %drawing grids on the spere invoking DLongredd and DrawLongitudeCirclered

    \foreach \t in {130,145,...,145} { \DLongredd[\R+3]{\t} }
    \foreach \t in {130,133,...,145} { \DrawLongitudeCirclered[\R+3]{\t} }

    \foreach \t in {0,30,...,30} { \DLatred[\R+3]{\t} }
    \foreach \t in {0,2,...,30} { \DrawLatitudeCirclered[\R+3]{\t} }

    %labelling
    \draw[-latex,thick](4,-5.5)node[left]{$\mathsf{Grid(s)\ in\ Fig. \ (\ref{fig:Grid})}$}
                 to[out=0,in=270] (5.8,-2.3);
    \draw[thick](3.6,-6)node[left]{$[\mathsf{Rectilinear}]$};

\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption[Representation of spherical and regular computational grids used by SWAN]
    {Representation of spherical (red) and cartesian (black) co-ordinate systems. Latter 
    gives an example of unstructured grids. Both unstructured. Conversion from former 
    to latter involves a deformation factor which is acceptable within a given spatial limit. 
    For my case, only unstructured flat meshes are employed (\textit{Lisboa} Geodetic 
    datum: black grid on the right). Confront above represented points ($P_1,P_2,P_3$) with 
    Fig.(\ref{fig:Grid}). \\Mathematically frames change accordingly: see Eq.(\ref{eq:actbal2sph}).}
    \label{fig:frames}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

**The result**
[image: The result]

Comment: It does not fix the issue completely. Find the update 2.

Comment: The downvote is too harsh -- if the post does not fix the problem, grant some time to improve it!

Comment: @Roboticist: I did not suspect you...

Comment: Ok, hope it's fixed !

Comment: @marsupilam: Sounds to be a good fix. Could you please explain something about the fix? You had asserted that `I don't exactly know how or why`

Comment: @marsupilam: You'd fixed the case with improvement of the main reference code. The challenging question is, actually, why the main author's code does not lead to his own answer, unless one posits that the reference code is wrong. I don't think so... The issue might be something related to compilation or something...

Comment: @Roboticist: AFAIK, the main code could not be wrong, as they are firstly tested, then placed among library of TikZ examples.

Comment: @Roboticist Have a look  at http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=25293 for an explanation. Newer versions of Tikz treat the code differently from the version that was used for the example.