# How to define \pgfkeyssetexpandedvalue?

Tags: expansion, token-lists

*Note: this question follows [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/346731/14500) about `\pgfkeyssetvalue`.*

The `\pgfkeyssetvalue` is defined in `pgfkeys.code.tex` file by:

```
\newtoks\pgfkeys@temptoks
% [...] 
\long\def\pgfkeyssetvalue#1#2{%
  \pgfkeys@temptoks{#2}\expandafter\edef\csname pgfk@#1\endcsname{\the\pgfkeys@temptoks}%
}
```

How to define `\pgfkeyssetexpandedvalue` as `\pgfkeyssetvalue` but where the second argument is expanded?

As this second argument can contains thinks like `#1`, ... `#9`, we can't use `\edef`.

PS: The `\pgfkeyssetexpandedvalue` macro can help to fix [this bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/306/) revealed by [“Example: Spherical and cartesian grids” isn't compiled to the right figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/346621/14500).

Comment: what do you mean by expanded here? (that is you clearly mean something different to the expansion done by edef, otherwise you could use edef) what do you want to happen to `#1` or `\def\foo{}` appearing within the argument, would you want `\foo` to expand to the value it had before the definition (which is what edef would do)?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle All sequences `#1`...`#9` (and may be `##`) should be kept as they are, `\def` is not expandable and `\foo` should be expanded.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ...Exactly as with `\edef` but without the error "Illegal parameter number in definition"! ;-)

Comment: so if `\foo` has been defined by `\def\foo{abc}` you want `\def\foo{}` in the argument to expand to `\def abc{}` and generate an error when used, just as it would in `\edef`  but `\def\foo#1{#1}` it normally doesn't make sense to keep `#1` as `#1` if  `\foo` has been expanded ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If `\foo` has been defined by `\def\foo{abc}`, I would like that `\pgfkeyssetexpandedvalue{xxx}{\foo{} #1 #2}` defines the same macro that `\pgfkeyssetvalue{xxx}{abc #1 #2}`... if possible!

Comment: yes but that's the easy case and didn't say what `\pgfkeyssetexpandedvalue{xxx}{\def\foo#1{}\foo{#2}}` should expand to, as `\pgfkeyssetexpandedvalue{xxx}{\def abc#1{}abc{#2}}` is not legal syntax

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The user knows the difference between normal and expanded values (or codes). In this case, we would provide `\pgfkeyssetexpandedvalue{xxx}{\def\noexpand\foo##1{...}\noexpand\foo{#2}}` as we would with `\edef`.

Comment: yes but... (and that's why I'm pushing for an answer) in an edef you have the option of `##` to control what happens to `#` but here  it passes through toks register so `#` processing is disabled which means in simple case you do not need to double it. easiest way to make it work like edef is to use edef, but then you have to double `#`. The only way I can think of allowing some version of edef expansion without needing to double `#` would be some rather fragile token-by-token parsing and re-constructing of the argument. Perhaps (as it's  a different command) just using edef would be OK?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have tried to use `\edef` but, if the value contains `#2`... `#9`, I got  the error "Illegal parameter number in definition"! as the `\csname pgfk@#1\endcsname` macro don't use parameters.

Comment: yes you'd have to use `##1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
\long\def\pgfkeyssetexpandvalue#1#2{%
  \edef\tmp##1##2##3##4##5##6##7##8##9{#2}%
  \expandafter\def\csname pgfk@#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter
  {\tmp{####1}{####2}{####3}{####4}{####5}{####6}{####7}{####8}{####9}}%
}


%% test:
\pgfkeyssetexpandvalue{xxx}{aha#1+#3}

\catcode`@=11
\show\pgfk@xxx  %% \pgfk@xxx=macro: aha##1+##3.

\end
```

**Edit:** Considering your comment (that you need to double all hashes, not only single hashes followed by numbers), you can try the following trick:

```
\newtoks\mytoks
\long\def\pgfkeyssetexpandvalue#1#2{%
   \mytoks={#2}%
   \scantokens\expandafter{\expandafter\mytoks\expandafter{\the\mytoks}}%
   \expandafter
      \edef\csname pgfk@#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\the\mytoks}%
}

%test
\pgfkeyssetexpandvalue{xxx}{abc#1+##3}

\catcode`@=11
\show\pgfk@xxx  % \pgfk@xxx=macro: abc##1+####3.

\bye
```

The line 4 of the code is the core of the trick: the hashes are doubled in `\mytoks` using `\scantokens`.

Comment: Very nice trick. I tried it in `pgfkeys.code.tex` and it seems to work.

Comment: There is still a problem: I can't use a value like `{\def\noexpand\foo##1{[##1]}\noexpand\foo{#1}}` (valid for`\edef`). The error is `! Illegal parameter number in definition`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit I don't understand your intent. The usage `\noexpand\foo{#1}` has no sense, because the `#1` parameter is out the definition body and out of parameter mask of `\foo`. The meaningful usage is only `{\def\noexpand\foo#1{[#1]}\noexpand\foo{something-real}}`

Comment: Your second proposition is very good. My last request: is it possible to use `\pgfkeys@temptoks` instead of `\mytoks`? (the catcode of `@` can cause problem to `\scantokens`).

Comment: @PaulGaborit If you need to use `@` in `\temptoks`, then you can try `\pgfkeys@temtoks=\scantokens\expandafter{\expandafter{\the\pgfkeys@temptoks}}`.